# php folder file location

Tags: php, path

`include "con.php"` would find the con.php file in the current folder.

`include "../con.php"` would find it in the folder above.

What is the syntax to find it in the folder 2 above?

and lastly, what is the syntax to find it in the folder which is in the same "above one" folder? (like if i have a folder MAIN, with foldersONE and TWO in it.  con.php is in TWO and the file to be run is in ONE)?

Thanks!

Comment: do not address files this way. Always use absolute path

Comment: Have to agree with @Col. Shrapnel. See my answer for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`../../con.php`

This would get you 2 levels up.

`../TWO/con.php`

Would take you one level up, and then down into `TWO` where con.php is.

Answer (score 1):

It's `../` for each folder, so `../../` for two folder.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not entirely on-topic, I'd recommend creating a define for your "base" HTML directory and accessing all includes, images, etc. relative to that. (If you have a specific "includes" directory, you could of course create a specific define for that as well.)

For example:

```
define('__BASEPATH', str_replace('//', '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'), true);
include __BASEPATH.'includes/con.php';
```